# Python MySQLQuery result returns extra characters

Tags: python, mysql

I'm making a mysql request with python, when I'm printing the result it gives me the results but it adds some characters extra for me xD

What I need is:

- Asia TAG
- Australia TAG
- ...

What I get is:

- ('Asia TAG',)
- ('Australia TAG',)
- ...

Those `('`...`',)` how does this get in my results?

```
current = con_mysql.cursor()
current_query = "SELECT name FROM event_categories WHERE visible=1"
current.execute(current_query)

for name in current:
    print(name)
```

Comment: Your query returns a _tuple_. Take the first index of the result to get your strings e.g. `print(name[0])`

Comment: @roganjosh, that simple... thank you for the helpout!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the records returned from MySQL are tuples, so you need to convert it to what you need, e.g.: `print(name[0])`

Comment: Thansk for your answer ;)

Comment: @LenapCapo no problem

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be using pythons built in format function to get a better output

```
current = con_mysql.cursor()
current_query = "SELECT name FROM event_categories WHERE visible=1"
current.execute(current_query)

for name in current:
    print("{}".format(name[0])
```